# How to connect to a Network SAMBA Printer in Ubuntu?

Tags: networking, printing

In my office all computers are Windows and my computer runs Ubuntu 18.04.

We are connected by same network where IPv4 default gateway is `192.168.1.246`, my IPv4 address is `192.168.1.111` and the the Windows computer to which the printer is connected has IPv4 address `192.168.1.114`
(the printer is shared by the Windows 8 computer).

How do I connect/print with the printer with my Ubuntu?

My printer is HP Laserjet M1005 MFP.

Comment: What is the type of the printer?

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Answer (score 5):

## Here is how to go about it in pictures

### System Setup > Devices Printers

[image]

Do not click on the Green Add... button on top. **Click on additional printer settings...** circled above.

### You should see a smaller window with **+Add** button on top left:

[image]

### In the New Printer window select *Windows Printer via SAMBA*:

[image]

Then fill in the printer server detail. You may also click the browse button and search for printer servers.

### Select **HP** as the printer manufacturer and then then scroll down to find your printer:

[image]

Click forward and complete the process.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You will need to install the driver foo2xqx. http://foo2xqx.rkkda.com/

According to the page you will need to perform following steps (open terminal and type in commands):

```
wget -O foo2zjs.tar.gz http://foo2zjs.rkkda.com/foo2zjs.tar.gz
tar zxf foo2zjs.tar.gz
cd foo2zjs
make

./getweb P1005     # Get HP LaserJet P1005 firmware file
./getweb P1006     # Get HP LaserJet P1006 firmware file
./getweb P1007     # Get HP LaserJet P1007 firmware file
./getweb P1008     # Get HP LaserJet P1008 firmware file
./getweb P1505     # Get HP LaserJet P1505 firmware file

sudo make install
sudo make install-hotplug
sudo make cups
sudo gnome-cups-manager
```

Adding the printer via command line using CUPS:

```
 lpadmin -p "NAME" -v "URI" -E -P /usr/share/cups/model/file.ppd.gz
 lpadmin -d "NAME"              # Set the default
```

Comment: This driver is already included in the default Ubuntu 18.04 installation. There is no need to install this driver.