# Usb printer on a router

Tags: networking, usb, printing, router

I have a Samsung USB printer that works fine with Windows and Linux when it is connected on a USB port. I recently got a new router (HUB 1000) which has a couple of USB port where I can plug my printer (and hopefully turn it into a network printer). When my printer is plugged to router, I can print from Windows but I can't print from my Linux system. All I had to tell Windows to get it to print was that my printer was here:
http://192.168.2.1:631. I tried doing the same with CUPS but it doesn't work. I also tried the printer management GUI but it didn't help. The error message is "print job was not accepted".
Also CUPS doesn't find the printer by itself.I tried other protocol too (ipp, lpd) but it always failed to print the test page.

Any help ?

Thanks

Edit:
Hi all, thanks for your feedback. I'm pretty sure I've done it right to "configure a network printer" like it is explained here: [How to configure a network printer in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/513713/how-to-configure-a-network-printer-in-ubuntu-14-04) . It's just that it doesn't work... The printer is a Samsung SCX-4521FG and I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS.  I've also typed localhost:631 in my browser. Then I was in CUPS 2.2.7 "user's interface". Clicked on "Adding printers and Classes". Then clicked on "Add a printer". Then I get a list of local printer that doesn't make much sense like CUPS-BRF. The "discovered network printer" is empty. In "other network printer" I selected http and continue.In the connection box I typed http:192.168.2.1:631 (as this is what works with Windows). I tried other protocols too like ipp but they all failed. At the end when I tried printing a test page, it didn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question [How to configure a network printer in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/513713/how-to-configure-a-network-printer-in-ubuntu-14-04) Or this one: [How to connect to a network SAMBA printer in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1075251/how-to-connect-to-a-network-samba-printer-in-ubuntu/1075291?r=SearchResults&s=2|38.0083#1075291)

Comment: what is the model name of printer ?

Comment: which version of ubuntu ?

Comment: Edit your question to elaborate on HOW you tried in Ubuntu. Port 631 on the router likely means that it's running CUPS, too.